# Checkbox en popup

Tags: css, checkbox

Estoy usando un popup para agregar contenido.
El popup replica llama a la misma plantilla que esta en la página. Funciona perfecto excepto por el selector de checkbox. Sucede esto, me selecciona con color el checkbox de la página, en lugar del activo.
El codigo que uso para el mismo es puro css
https://codepen.io/quinlo/pen/ReMRXz

¿alguna sugerencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si estás usando id's tal vez ese sea el problema. En el mismo DOM no puede haber dos id's idénticas.

Comment: era eso! <li> <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="checkboxOne3" value="#casa"><label for="checkboxOne3">Casa</label></li>, como puedo reemplazarlo?

Comment: lo reemplace    <li> <label><input type="checkbox" name="status"  value="#casa"><span class="ok">Casa</span></label></li> y se soluciono! Gracias!!